# Connect to email via Ruby

Tags: ruby, email

I really love the way ruby-gmail gem allows me to have complete control of gmail via ruby.  Unfortunately the HTML stripping 'feature' of gmail is problematic.  What is a good email gem and email hosting provider for automating email through ruby.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: jrhicks:  Did you ever find something that fit your question?

Comment: I was wrong, gmail does not strip the HTML.  Instead the HTML was being stripped for "forwarded" emails.  When gmail received the files directly, it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a gem, but I've had good luck with the `net/imap` library (included with Ruby).

I have some example code here:  http://github.com/benjaminoakes/snippets/blob/master/ruby/gmail_imap.rb

I've only tried reading email so far, so YMMV.